# Google Text-to-Speech API: how to set the speech speed?

Tags: perl, google-text-to-speech

I am using [this Perl script](https://github.com/Glutanimate/simple-google-tts/blob/master/speak.pl)
for Google Text-to-Speech (TTS) on Debian

It works like a charm, except the Google voice talks really slowly. I want to change that and make it talk faster.

Lines 174-179 control the breaks between words and sentences, but the words themselves come at a specific speed from Google.

I guess it could be changed somewhere around line 366 where the TTS call happens.

There is also `$sample_rate` all over that script, which might have something to do with that, but I cannot figure it out.

Any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: I don't think the sample rate has something to do with that. Thats the quality of the digital encoding of the sound. Look it up on Wikipedia. It's a value in Hz. You might know it from DVDs. I think the speed is either controlled by the api and you have to find it in the docs, or you cannot change it.

Comment: The script uses [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net) to post-process the response from Google, you could use options there to manipulate the file and change the speed.

Comment: I tried messing with sox, if I use sox ... speed 1.5 or so it comes to the speed I want, but sounds like a child on Helium, thats not good... Raising the speach speed on an Android Device does not do that, thus lets me suspect thers a Api Command for that, but I cannot find any...